# carrierwave al editar no encuentra la ruta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy usando la gema *Carrierwave* para subir *pdf*; está funcionando correctamente al crear, pero el inconveniente es al editar, si guardo me lleva al `show` y me figura el siguiente error:

> No route matches [POST] "/client/5" (ejemplo).

Lo curioso es que si hago clic sobre la *url* en el navegador + *enter*, me dirige bien al `show`.

En mis *routes.rb* tengo:

```
resources :clients
```

Código de `update`:

```
def update
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])

  if @client.update(client_params)
    redirect_to clients_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end # end if
end # end update
```

rails routes
[image: rails routes]

Form:
https://pastebin.com/Y9EjEJvB

Que también me llama la atención, no entiendo por qué me redirige al `show` cuando le indico que vaya al `clients_path`.

¿A alguien le ha pasado algo parecido?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código completo de la acción (i.e. `update`) donde se genera el error? También incluye el resultado que obtienes con `$ rails routes`.

Comment: actualizada la consulta, tendria que agregar algo mas ?

Comment: Deberías usar un `PUT` para actualizar, no un `POST`. Yo creo que tu error está en la vista, agrega el formulario de edición.

Comment: Agregue el form en pastebin, no me dejo agregarlo stack.
Es el mismo form que tengo para crear, hasta antes de agregar la parte que suba archivos funcionaba correctamente.

Comment: Solucionado, el problema era el :method => "post", tiene que ser put o simplemente sacandolo ya que si pongo put no funciona para el create

Comment: No se debe poner Solucionado en el titulo, lo adecuado es publicar una respuesta como lo indica @MauricioAriasOlave, asi ayudas a la comunidad con tu solucion.

Comment: Listo, conteste la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era en `:method => "post"` en el `form`, tiene que ser `put` o simplemente sacándolo, ya que si pongo `put` no funciona para el `create`.

Comment: Gracias por publicar tu respuesta. Por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.